# With VBA, get pivot table values in sorted order

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

In Excel VBA, I followed these steps:

```
Created a pivot table off another sheet as datasource
AutoSort the first pivot field based on the first data field
```

The pivot table is displaying everything correctly. Now I'm trying to programmatically access the rows under the first pivot field, and get them in the sort order. But the PivotTable.RowFields collection is returning rows in the original order before sorting. How can I programmatically get rows in the new, sorted order, without writing code to sort the data?

Abstract code snippet

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim strval As String
.
.
.
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("first")
pf.AutoSort xlDescending, "firstdata", pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1
strval = ptExtract.RowFields(1).PivotItems(1)
```

After these statements, the pivot table does display all values in descending orders. But strval gets the value from the first row before sorting. The order of pivot items in PivotItems does not seem to change after AutoSort. So how do I get these values in the newly sorted order?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just copy the whole range with the sorted row fields rather than getting it via PivotTable Object?? Is it not convenient for you?

Comment: Thanks, took me a minute to realize what you're suggesting. I suppose it's the next best thing, not ideal. That column's values are separated by empty cells. I would rather stick to a method than do workarounds, hardcoding cell locations etc (the pivot table is created dynamically) etc.

Comment: Actually there are also subtotals in there, so in addition to empty cells there's also duplicates of the same pivot field value etc. I'm hoping for a better way.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am facing this exact same problem in excel 2019. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem and used this:

strval = pf.LabelRange.Offset(1)

It circumvents the need for any use of pivotitems, not sure how to change the syntax if multiple labels are used or if you want the same from datarange.